# Convert zip to gzip and upload to S3 bucket

Tags: python, python-2.x, compression, ftp, amazon-s3

My code accesses an FTP server, downloads a `.zip` file, pushes the file contents as `.gz` to an AWS S3 bucket.

```
import boto3
import ftplib
import gzip
import io
import zipfile

def _move_to_s3(fname):
    host = 'some_host'
    user = 'some_user'
    passwd = 'some_password'

    tmp_dir = '/tmp/'
    tmp_fname = fname.split('.')[0] + '.gz'

    target_bucket = 'some_bucket'
    s3 = boto3.resource('s3')

    try:
        ftp = ftplib.FTP(host, user, passwd)

        with io.BytesIO() as data, gzip.open(tmp_dir + tmp_fname, 'wb') as gz:
            ftp.retrbinary('RETR ' + fname, data.write)
            gz.write(data.getvalue())

        s3.Object(target_bucket, tmp_fname).put(Body=open(tmp_dir + tmp_fname, 'rb'))
    except Exception as e:
        print e
    finally:
        ftp.quit()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    _move_to_s3('some_file.zip')
```

I welcome any comments but my main points of interest are:

- Assuming the source zip contains only one text file, is it OK to
  write to the gzip file from a stream containing the contents of the
  downloaded zip file?
- I think I should change the code to hold the gzip in memory, without generating temporary files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks okay to me in general.  I'd prefer to pass in configuration
separately, parsed from a config file or command line arguments, but if
it's a one-off script it's probably okay this way.

The temporary files aren't deleted as far as I see; consider using the
[`tempfile` module](https://docs.python.org/2/library/tempfile.html) to
allocate and delete temporary files automatically.

Also, while the string to bytes conversion works as is, it's also
brittle when used with large files, e.g. larger then the amount of RAM
available, because it will store the downloaded file in memory.  I'd
suggest passing in `gz.write` directly instead:

```
with gzip.open(tmp_dir + tmp_fname, 'wb') as gz:
    ftp.retrbinary('RETR ' + fname, gz.write)
```

Unless I'm mistaken that should keep the bytes in order; if not you
could still pass in a function that converts *only* the downloaded chunk
to `bytes` and calls `gz.write` on the converted value.

Regarding your questions:

- Since there's no extraction of data from the zip file, I don't see how
  that matters.  If you were to extract something (a single file) from
  the zip file, then yes, gzipping that will of course be okay.  Make
  sure that the gzipped files are how you expect them (i.e. a single
  compressed text file) and that you don't need the file name or other
  attributes in the original zip archive.  At the moment you basically
  upload `some_file.zip.gz` to S3, as in, two compressions nested.
  Probably not what you want.
- As argued above that's probably not advisable unless you know that the
  data fits into memory.  If it does, sure, why not.

Some more remarks:

- The `zipfile` import is unused, as mentioned above.
- Prefer
  [`os.path.join`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.path.html#os.path.join)
  to concatenating strings.
- `fname`/`passwd` instead of `filename`/`password` seems pointless
  truncation.
- `print` should be used as a function to be forwards compatible,
  i.e. `print(e)` instead.
- The result of `tmp_dir + tmp_fname` should be reused instead of
  writing the same expression twice.